# Spring Integration :How to send array as a single payload to a jdbc : outbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

How to send array as a single payload to a jdbc : outbound gateway of Spring Integration ? 
I am constructing an array of string and sending it to the interface method . However the SQL accepts one parameter ":payload"  and it fails with UncategorizedSQLException.

The Sql query of outbound gateway is as below

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway data-source="dataSource"   request-channel="requestChannel" 
                           query="select XMLMSG from Table where SEQ_ID in (:payload)"                                
                           reply-channel="replyChannel" > 

</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>

serviceinterface.findBySequenceIds(sequenceIdStringArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually to `substituteNamedParameters` for `IN` clause the parameter has to be `Collection` not `array`. The source code of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.substituteNamedParameters`:

```
if (value instanceof Collection) {
    Iterator<?> entryIter = ((Collection<?>) value).iterator();
    int k = 0;
        while (entryIter.hasNext()) {
    if (k > 0) {
        actualSql.append(", ");
        }

......
      actualSql.append("?");
```

So, just construct `List` from your strings, not `array`:

```
Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

And your real query will be:

```
select XMLMSG from Table where SEQ_ID in (?, ?, ?)
```

Other work the `JdbcTemplate` will do for you.

**UPDATE**

Note, by default `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway/>` selects only one record. To get rid this limit specify `max-rows-per-poll="0"`.

Comment: Spring Integration utilises configuration file where its not possible to dynamically construct the SQL query for the count of named parameters.

Comment: No, your configuration is OK. Your issue is aroud a type of `payload`. I said `real` query and meant that it will be that what will be sent to the DB. I know what to do Spring Integration. You have to just change the array `payload` to the `List`

Comment: Thanks , let me try this approach. I will keep you posted.

Comment: I tried this approach ,however only one record (xml payload) is picked up by the replychannel / rowmapper .Please advise.

Comment: 1. Does your `SELECT` really return several records? 2. How do you build `List` payload for query parameter? 3. Haven't you tried to debug, at least your code ?

Comment: (1)yes . I am passing multiple primary keys to the SELECT. (2)I have a String [] and then do Arrays.asList(String[])

Comment: let me rephrase the previous comment, I am passing multiple primary keys to the SELECT and hence am expecting multiple records.However only one record is picked up.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Sorry, that I took your time

Comment: Thanks , However I am using Spring Integration 2.2 and it does not have the max-rows-per-poll="0" property. Please advise.

Comment: It Works . Thanks a lot Artem . In the config xml file it shows an error saying that the max-rows-per-poll attribute is not allowed on the int-jdbc:outboundgateway . However I am able to fetch multiple results through my RowMapper to Java codebase.